# Extract specific rows from SAS dataset based on a particular cell value of a variable

Tags: sas

I want to extract specific set of rows from a large SAS dataset based on a particular cell value of a variable into a new dataset. In this dataset, I have 6 variables. Following is an example of this dataset:

```
Variable names:   Var1      Var2      Var3   Var4   Var5  Var6
Row 1              A          1        2     3       4     5
Row 2              B          1        2     3       4     5
Row 3              A          1        2     3       4     5
Row 4              B          1        2     3       4     5
Row 5              Sample     1        2     3       4     5
Row 6              A          1        2     3       4     5
Row 7              B          1        2     3       4     5
Row 8              A          1        2     3       4     5
Row 9              B          1        2     3       4     5
Row 10             A          1        2     3       4     5
Row 11             B          1        2     3       4     5
Row 12             A          1        2     3       4     5
Row 13             B          1        2     3       4     5
```

From this dataset, I want to select a set of next 8 rows starting from a row in which Var 1 has a value = "Sample". I want to extract multiple such sets of 8 rows from this dataset into a new dataset. Can someone please guide me how I can accomplish this in SAS?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think your terminology is clear.  What do you mean by `extract`?

Comment: I would like to apologize for not making this clear. Its a very confusing problem to explain in writing. I will try my best to explain this again.

Comment: I want to select (extract) multiple sets of 8 rows from this dataset into a new dataset. These sets are located at uneven intervals in this dataset. In other words,  there are many other rows in between these sets, which I don’t need. The only common pattern for all of these sets is that they have a preceding row in which the value of Var1 variable is "Sample". My question is in the following post.

Comment: My question is that can I write a condition using this value (Sample) of VAR1 such that it will allow me to select the next  8 rows (In this example: Row 6-Row 13) into a new dataset? I hope this clarifies my problem

Answer (score 1):

Would the [`output`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/69738/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1lltvbis7ye1an1eryo4leh2mck.htm) statement work for you?

```
data have;
    infile datalines dsd dlm=",";
    input   Variable_names  : $char10.
            Var1            : $char10.
            Var2            : 8.
            Var3            : 8.
            Var4            : 8.
            Var5            : 8.
            Var6            : 8.;
    datalines;
Row 1 , A     , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Row 2 , B     , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Row 3 , A     , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Row 4 , B     , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Row 5 , Sample, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Row 6 , A     , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Row 7 , B     , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Row 8 , A     , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Row 9 , B     , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Row 10, A     , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Row 11, B     , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Row 12, A     , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Row 13, B     , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
;
run;

data want_without
     want_with;
    set have;
    if strip(Var1) = "Sample" then output want_with;
    else                           output want_without;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I don't want the row with cell value of "Sample" for Var1 in the new dataset. I want the following 8 rows (Row 6 - Row 13) in the new dataset. I want to select (extract) multiple sets of such 8 rows from this dataset into a new dataset. These sets are located at uneven intervals in this dataset. In other words,  there are many other rows in between these sets, which I don’t need. The only common pattern for all of these sets is that they have a preceding row in which the value of Var1 variable is "Sample". My question is in the following post.

Comment: My question is that can I write a condition using this value (Sample) of VAR1 such that it will allow me to select the next  8 rows (In this example: Row 6-Row 13) into a new dataset?

Comment: If it is always 8 rows after (or including?) a "Sample" row, then I suggest Quentin's answer. Do you need multiple datasets? Or just output 8 rows into _one_ other dataset?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to set a counter to 8 whenever the previous record has var1="Sample", and then decrement the counter for each record.  And only output records where counter is >= 1.

```
data want ;
  set have ;

  if lag(var1) = "Sample" then counter = 8 ;
  else counter+(-1) ;  *counter is implicitly retained ;

  if counter>=1 then output ;
  * drop counter ;
run ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a counter and output as desired, use the RETAIN coupled with an IF (& OUTPUT) statement. You may need to tweak the IF condition but I think you get the idea here.

```
data want;
set have;
retain counter 10; 
if strip(Var1) = "Sample" then counter=1;
else counter+1;
if 2<=counter<=9 then OUTPUT;
*if 2<=counter<=9; *this is the same as above, but less code;
run;
```

Comment: This would output rows 2-4, which isn't wanted.

Comment: I think it would work if you used `retain counter 999;` or some such, so the counter starts with an arbitrarily high value.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed now.

Comment: Hello all,   I tried using @Reeza's approach and it worked very well. I have also tried using Quentin's approach and it was also very helpful. Thank you very much guys for helping me with this.